# [Unhandled promise rejection: Error: Expected URL scheme 'http' or 'https' but was 'file']

Tags: react-native, expo, pixi.js

Error:
[Unhandled promise rejection: Error: Expected URL scheme 'http' or 'https' but was 'file']

I tried to use the pixi js on the react-native expo project.

This is package.json file.

```
"dependencies": {
    "@expo/vector-icons": "^9.0.0",
    "expo": "^33.0.7",
    "expo-asset-utils": "^1.1.1",
    "expo-gl": "~5.0.1",
    "expo-pixi": "^1.1.0",
    "expokit": "^32.0.3",
    "lodash": "^4.17.11",
    "native-base": "^2.10.0",
    "prop-types": "^15.6.2",
    "react": "16.8.3",
    "react-dom": "^16.8.6",
    "react-native": "https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-33.0.0.tar.gz",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "^1.0.9",
    "react-native-svg": "^9.11.1",
    "react-native-web": "^0.11.2",
    "react-navigation": "^3.0.9",
    "react-navigation-redux-helpers": "^2.0.9",
    "react-redux": "^6.0.0",
    "react-style-proptype": "^3.2.2",
    "redux": "^4.0.1",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.3.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-preset-expo": "^5.0.0",
    "expo-cli": "^2.10.1",
    "eslint": "^5.16.0",
    "eslint-config-universe": "^1.0.7",
    "prettier": "^1.17.0"
  },
  "resolutions": {
    "expo-pixi/@expo/browser-polyfill": "0.0.1-alpha.3"
  },
  "private": true
```

And app.json file.

```
...

"privacy": "unlisted",
    "sdkVersion": "33.0.0",
    "platforms": [
      "ios",
      "android"
    ],
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "orientation": "portrait",
    "icon": "./src/assets/images/icon.png",
    "splash": {
      "image": "./src/assets/images/splash.png",
      "resizeMode": "cover",
      "backgroundColor": "#222222"
    },
    "updates": {
      "fallbackToCacheTimeout": 0
    },
    "assetBundlePatterns": [
      "**/*"
    ],
    "ios": {
      "supportsTablet": true
    }

...
```

This is my screen code.

```
import React from 'react';
import { GLView } from 'expo-gl';
import ExpoPixi,{ PIXI } from 'expo-pixi';

export default class GameReady extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <GLView
        style={{ flex: 1 }}
        onContextCreate={async context => {
          const sprite = await PIXI.Sprite.fromExpoAsync('https://ubisafe.org/images/sans-transparent-8-bit.png');
          const app = new PIXI.Application({ context });
          app.stage.addChild(sprite);
        }}
      />
    );
  }
}
```

Error:

```
[Unhandled promise rejection: Error: Expected URL scheme 'http' or 'https' but was 'file']

Stack trace:
  node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\NativeModules.js:155:41 in createErrorFromErrorData
  node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\NativeModules.js:104:55 in <unknown>
  node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:414:4 in __invokeCallback
  node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:127:28 in <unknown>
  node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:314:10 in __guard
  node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:126:17 in invokeCallbackAndReturnFlushedQueue
  ...
```

I run this project as expo start.
But I get the above erorr.
How can I fix this issue?
Help me.
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please look at fixed snack example with local sprites and on the web:

https://snack.expo.io/@djalik/base-pixi.js

Comment: Thanks for your response.
But it does not work for me.
And this is not an error, it's a warning.
It is important it can not see the result screen.

Comment: Would please lock at this warning screen?
http://prntscr.com/peyi1t

Comment: Now you have  another error , can you try change your code as described here in side effect section also pay attention how to work with sprites:https://github.com/expo/expo-pixi/blob/master/README.md

Comment: I updated the answer, please change sprite code  like I wrote.

Comment: I changed the code as you mentioned above, but It shows me another warning and the image doesn't render. [This is the result screen.] (http://prntscr.com/peywcf).

Comment: What parameter/url  did you put in  
  const sprite = await  ExpoPIXI.spriteAsync

Comment: This is an error image after I updated the sprites. http://prntscr.com/pez3bf

Comment: Can you post  png url in your code of sprite ExpoPIXI.spriteAsync(...)

Comment: I used this code as `const sprite = await PIXI.Sprite.fromExpoAsync('http://i.imgur.com/uwrbErh.png');`

Comment: You have to change as described in answer: const sprite = await ExpoPIXI.spriteAsync('https://ubisafe.org/images/sans-transparent-8-bit.png');

Comment: I just changed the code like that but it doesn't work for me.
http://prntscr.com/pezcma

Comment: I will update the expo-pixi npm version and let you know the result. thanks.

Comment: By the way you have another problem and not that you have in your  question. The previous one is solved. If you will receive the error of deprecated try to change again to version of sprite use to previous one.

Comment: I updated the expo-pixi library but the same issue.
And do you think about the `ExpoPIXI.spriteAsync(...) deprecated`?
Wouldn't it be better to use this? `await PIXI.Sprite.fromExpoAsync(...)`?

Comment: If you have error about deprecated, use code that described in warning.

Comment: const sprite = await PIXI.Sprite.fromExpoAsync('http://i.imgur.com/uwrbErh.png')

Comment: I used the code described in warning, but I can get another issue.
http://prntscr.com/pezqt8

Comment: Can you validate the code in answer (updated): imports and url that I wrote in answer...

Comment: I used the updated code, but another issue.
http://prntscr.com/pf00iy.

Comment: According to warning you are using wrong url for png resource, did you set the png url of your app and not that you posted in comments

Comment: Can you try this  png url: 'https://www.fnordware.com/superpng/pngtest8rgba.png', updated in answer

Comment: I used this code `const sprite = await PIXI.Sprite.fromExpoAsync('http://fnordware.com/superpng/pngtest8rgba.png');`
But same issue.

Comment: Https, please look at answer, copy it as is.

Comment: It doesn't seem to be a problem with the image path.

Comment: I updated the code like this `const sprite = await PIXI.Sprite.fromExpoAsync('https://fnordware.com/superpng/pngtest8rgba.png');`.
But it doesn't work. Same issue.

Comment: i build for you snack example without problems: https://snack.expo.io/@djalik/base-pixi.js 
used expo-pixi": "1.2.0"

Comment: I just saw this result, but I could not see the image on the result screen.
What do you think about this?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/200421/discussion-on-answer-by-oleg-unhandled-promise-rejection-error-expected-url-s).

Comment: i put the png to assets : https://snack.expo.io/@djalik/base-pixi.js

Comment: Thanks for your help. It works well now as assets png.
Additional, would you please let me know how to load the cloud image? `https://` or `http://`

Comment: I updated the snack with http example also. Please look at it again.